# Android DependencyInjected context at view classes

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-context

Why is keeping the context as an instance variable like:

```
Context mContext = DependencyInjectionService.getInstance(Application.class)
```

considered not a good practice at Android view classes? Instead using `getContext()` is said to be better but I couldn't find an explanation for it.

Comment: What do you mean by "is better"? For what purpose? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: What I meant by better is not giving heavy work on View classes. For data modules it doesn't matter but view classes it degrades the performance. I went over Android documentations but there is no strong argument for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, thanks for explaining your point is about performance. Well API's for dependency injection (DI Frameworks) have much overhead. A dependency can be singleton scoped, require multi injection, need extra constructorarguments etc. They can be used for basically all kinds of dependencies.This makes them very generic. However, because of all the overhead and possibilities, performance is not strong point of it. getContext does not check if a dependency requires multi injection or is singleton scoped etc. It just returns the context. This makes getContext good for performance but not a method that can be used for all kinds of objects. If you just have a look at the naming of the methods: "getContext" knows that it needs to return: the context. "getInstance" needs to find out what to return (which may be the context).